hat does gpg: skipped "user": no secret key mean?? (How to solve)? GPG4WIN
I am doing a git commit and I am getting the following error:
gpg: skipped "user <email>": No secret key
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object

I do have a secret key and isnt it generated by itself when doing key generation RSA and RSA with GPG4WIN??
I do have gpg.program=c:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe
